# passing variables into Invoke-WebRequest -uri argument powershell

Tags: powershell, hyperlink, scraper

a site has a directory structure like this:

https://web.site.net/documents/2018/

where 2018 is the year

my code is like this:

```
$year = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter Year'
(Invoke-WebRequest -uri 'https://web.site.net/documents/$year/').Links.href | 
Select-string 'https://web.site.net/documents/$year/#'
```

How do I properly escape, so that the year properly goes into the url?

Answer (score 2):

Try using double quotes instead of single quotes. In Powershell, double quotes around a value signify that variable names should be substituted for their contents. On the other hand, single-quoted values are treated as literals.

```
(Invoke-WebRequest -uri "https://web.site.net/documents/$year/").Links.href | 
Select-string "https://web.site.net/documents/$year/#"
```

[See this page for more information about single versus double quotes in Powershell.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules?view=powershell-6)